# App crashes when trying to join private beta sites

Tags: bug, android-app, private-beta

*[Apparently, private beta sites can be seen from Android app](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2546668#2546668). While that might be another bug, that's not the subject here.*

On the other hand, when trying to join these sites (e.g. by voting a post), the app will prompt you to join the site. After clicking "Join Site", the app will crash with the following stack trace:

```
10-20 08:49:44.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 08:49:44.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2332): Process: com.stackexchange.marvin, PID: 2332
10-20 08:49:44.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2332): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.stackexchange.stacman.extensions.UserCreation.getJustCreated()' on a null object reference
10-20 08:49:44.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2332):     at com.stackexchange.marvin.Current$CreateUserOnSiteAsyncTask.onPostExecute(Current.java:885)
10-20 08:49:44.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2332):     at com.stackexchange.marvin.Current$CreateUserOnSiteAsyncTask.onPostExecute(Current.java:859)
10-20 08:49:44.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2332):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
10-20 08:49:44.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2332):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-20 08:49:44.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2332):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
10-20 08:49:44.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2332):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-20 08:49:44.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2332):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-20 08:49:44.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-20 08:49:44.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-20 08:49:44.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-20 08:49:44.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

Since I don't have any experience in private beta sites, I'm not sure these suggestions are reasonable:

1. Prevent "Join Site" dialog at all and tell user that "This site is currently in private beta. You cannot join until it is in public beta."
2. Show a dialog with message "This site is currently in private beta. If you want to join, you have to commit to the proposal in Area 51.", with buttons "Cancel" and "Open Proposal" to view the proposal in browser.

(Do you have better suggestions? Please post it! :)

Specs:

- Stack Exchange: 1.0.51
- Android model: Nexus 4
- Android version: 4.4.4

Comment: Regarding being able to browse private beta, it's [by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200064/committed-but-non-invited-area-51-private-beta-is-accessible-via-android-app)