# What is documentation beta site?

Tags: support, bug, android-app, beta-sites, documentation-beta

In my installation of the Stack Exchange Android app, I found **Documentation beta** in the all sites list in which there is only one question saying "Welcome to Stack Overflow documentation Beta!". When I try to join the site, the app crashes.

But I cannot find it in the all sites list on the website. What is this site and why can't I join this site in the app and why can't I find it on the website?

I can't even find it on Area 51.

Comment: Related posts: [browsing private beta on SE app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200064/committed-but-non-invited-area-51-private-beta-is-accessible-via-android-app) and [crash when trying to join private beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242321/app-crashes-when-trying-to-join-private-beta-sites)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The site is our testing ground for the Documentation feature. During the feature's private beta, we're going to invite users who signed up to help us test it. Eventually, the site will be taken down and the data and whatnot moved to Stack Overflow proper.

As for why trying to join crashes the app... that sounds like a problem with private beta handling. I'll ping an Android dev to see what's what.

Comment: It might be good to know you can actually open the private beta in the iOS app. It shows one question from Kevin.

Comment: @PatrickHofman That's fine. It's not a secret or anything. But thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Okay. Do you want me to report that separately or will you follow it up from this one?

Comment: @PatrickHofman No need to report it. I'll ask around, but I'm pretty sure this is a non-issue.

Comment: Okay. Is there never sensitive data put in private betas?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Not really. Anything that we need to keep fully private we keep off of the prod tier. Granted, there's usually a first time for everything... but I think we're okay for the time being.

Answer (score 5):

The [Documentation feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow), which will initially be developed for SO only (and hopefully later extended to other sites), is not yet ready for beta testing. Presumably the fact that it exists in any form is just a glitch, but it's unsurprising that you can't do anything with it yet.