# Searching for sites on Android and getting extra results

Tags: bug, search, android-app

Android app 1.0.77. I select "All sites...", enter "fina", get the following suggestions:

- Personal Finance & Money
- Quantitative Finance
- Space Exploration

Now, nowhere in the SEx.SE description do I see any words containing "fina".

*P.S. Happy New Year!*

Comment: Well, since SE apps use SE API, the difference in behaviour is quite apparent... including [showing private betas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200064/committed-but-non-invited-area-51-private-beta-is-accessible-via-android-app). Seems [meta-tag:status-bydesign]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is the *The Final Frontier*. That sounds scarier then it is, so hold on.

Calling [/info](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info#filter=!9YdnSFfpS&site=space&run=true) on the API to get the site info you'll find in the aliases (the other DNS names the site can be reached at) for Space Exploration the following:

```
"site": {
        "aliases": [
          "http://thefinalfrontier.stackexchange.com"
        ],
```

Your search term *fina* matches on that alias.

Comment: And as a further proof, searching `three` will show *3D Printing* (private beta) since it has an alias of `threedprinting.stackexchange.com`